# Why Won't My Inputs in a form with a Get method work together?

Tags: php, forms, html, input

I have two inputs that I'd like to use as a part of the same form. Each one delivers a variable which is used to modify a WP_User_Query to get users based on a large number of search fields. Both of them deliver a $_GET to the url bar perfectly, but only when they're working alone. When both are on the page, entering a value for either one and pressing return will do nothing.

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink() ?>" method="get">
  <?php
  $inst = receiveGET(instrument_search);
  $search_field = receiveGET(user_search);

  /* all the WP_User_Query stuff goes here, and it's all working properly */
  <!-- If this input is deleted, the other input works perfectly. -->
  <table id="musician-field" class="form-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input title="Search User" name="user_search" maxlength="21" placeholder="Search Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET[user_search]); ?>" ></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- If this input is deleted, the other input works perfectly. -->
  <table id="instrument-field" class="form-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input title="Search Instrument" name="instrument_search" maxlength="21" placeholder="Search Instrument" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET[instrument_search]); ?>" ></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  /* All the loop stuff is here and it's also working properly */

  /* The form close tab is way below a lot of PHP and HTML, 
  but I have the same bug happen when I move it up to be 
  directly enclosing the inputs */

  </form>
```

I know all the variables are going through properly, so I'm positive this is stemming from my poor understanding of how forms work, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Anyone care to enlighten me?

Comment: This is browser behavior- the enter key only submits forms with a single field and no submit button.

Comment: So I could fix it by adding a submit button?